# How to install google chrome in CentOS 6.9?

Tags: google-chrome, centos, chromium, yum, chromium-embedded

I've tried to find a way to install `google chrome` in CentOS 6.9.

Someone says google had stopped supporting, and the others have different ways to do it.

But their solutions did not help me.

Does anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the guy that helped us installing Chrome on CentOS 6.

https://chrome.richardlloyd.org.uk/

But it's no way for now, as he mentioned:

> In July 2013, I released a bash script that would allow RHEL/CentOS 6
>   users to continue to run the latest Google Chrome release, despite
>   official support for that platform being dropped from Google Chrome 28
>   onwards.
>
> Sadly, the release of Google Chrome 59 (and later versions) meant a
>   switch to GTK+3, which was impossible for my script to workaround on
>   RHEL/CentOS 6. Hence, this site has been shut down and the script is
>   no longer of any use to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it seems like there's no way to install chrome in `CentOS 6.9 i386`.

I found a post which explains why google chrome does not support to CentOS anymore.

[Why google does not support chrome to CentOS anymore?](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53768)

I hope this post can help somebody like me.